# How can i display my inserted record with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am just beginner in laravel i am inserting data in my database using ajax but display time somehow ajax not work, 
i just want that i want to insert and display the data using ajax.

Right now it is working like than when I add data from model and click on submit the all data submit in database successfully but it is not displaying, for display the inserted data I have to refresh the page, Instead of that i wanna do all the operation with ajax

this is my controller to insert liquor product

```
public function storeLiquorInventory(LiquorProductRequest $request)
    {
        $liquorInputs = $request->only($this->fillableLiquorItem);
        try{
            $liquorInputs['created_by'] = auth()->user()->id;
            $liquorInputs['updated_by'] = auth()->user()->id;
            $liquorInventory = StandLiquorInventory::create($liquorInputs);
            return response()->json(['type' => 'success']);
        }
        catch(Exception $ex) {
            return response()->json(['type' => 'error']);
        }
    }
```

This is method to display the data

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $stand = Stand::with('standsLiquor', 'standsNonChargeable')->findOrFail($id);

        $standUserList = EventStandUser::select('user_id')->where('stand_id',$id)->with(['user'=>function($q){ return $q->selectRaw('id,concat(first_name," ",last_name) as fullname')->where('status','approved');}])->get()->map(function($cu){
            return ['id'=>$cu->user->id,'fullname'=>$cu->user->fullname];
        })->pluck('fullname','id');

        return view('admin.stand.index',compact('stand','standUserList'));
    }
```

This my routes

```
    Route::resource('stand-sheet', 'Admin\StandSheetController');
    Route::post('stand-sheet/store-liquor', 'Admin\StandSheetController@storeLiquorInventory');
```

This is my js file code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('stand_liquor_table').length > 0) {
            ajax: {
            url: "/stand-sheet",
            data: function (d) {
                    d.type = $('#stand_liquor_table select[name=type]').val();
                    d.brand = $('#stand_liquor_table select[name=brand]').val();
                    d.start = $('#stand_liquor_table select[name=start]').val();
                    d.xfer_in = $('#stand_liquor_table select[name=xfer_in]').val();
                    d.end = $('#stand_liquor_table select[name=end]').val();
                    d.used = $('#stand_liquor_table select[name=used]').val();
                },
            type: 'POST',
            dataSrc: function(json) {
                for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
                    json.data[i].type = json.data[i].type;
                    json.data[i].brand = json.data[i].brand;
                    json.data[i].start = json.data[i].start;
                    json.data[i].xfer_in = json.data[i].xfer_in;
                    json.data[i].end = json.data[i].end;
                    json.data[i].used = json.data[i].used;
                }
                return json.data;
            },

            columns: [
                { data: 'type', name: 'type' },
                { data: 'brand', name: 'brand' },
                { data: 'start', name: 'start' },
                { data: 'xfer_in', name: 'xfer_in' },
                { data: 'end', name: 'end' },
                { data: 'used', name: 'used' },
            ],
        }
    }

  });

   addLiquor = function (form) {
        registerAjaxCall('/stand-sheet/store-liquor', 'POST', $(form).serializeArray(), function (response) {
            if (response.type == 'success') {
                // console.log($(form).serializeArray());
                $('#addNewLiquorModel').modal('hide');
                toast('Success', 'Liquor Successfully Added', 'success');
            }else {
                toast('Error', 'Failed to add liquor', 'error');
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a post response with AJAX doesn't mean that the HTML page will be refreshed by itself, the only way to do it is to use javascript and changing the HTML code.

There are two main problems that we should fix so you can get the result that you're expecting:

1. send back the new liquor record on your JSON success response.
2. update the DOM when the response.type is "success".

So first, let's try to fix the backend. it is quite simple, we just need to include the 
`$liquorInventory` on the JSON response ( in your `storeLiquorInventory` method ):

```php
return response()->json(['type' => 'success' , 'newLiquor' => $liquorInventory ]);
```

Now, on the JS part, we should change the DOM, I don't know how your HTML tree looks like but I'll try to give you an idea. start by editing the addLiquor function on your JS file where we will retrieve the newLiquor from the response, capture the List where we want to add our new liquor using jquery and add the wanted DOM to the tree.

```js
 if (response.type == 'success') {
                // console.log($(form).serializeArray());
                $('#addNewLiquorModel').modal('hide');
                toast('Success', 'Liquor Successfully Added', 'success');
                var LiquorList = $('#liquorList'); // select your list parent
                // include the HTML code that you want to add ( i'll use a separate function )
               liquorList.innerHTML = liquorList.innerHTML + createLiquorDOM(response.newLiquor)
}
```

the function createLiquorDOM will take the liquor received by the server as a parameter, and return an HTML code that we add to our list

```js
function createLiquorDOM( liquor ) {
return `<li>
          <p> name : ${liquor.name} </p> 
          <p>price : ${liquor.price}</p>
       </li>`;
}
```

of course, this is just an example, I don't know how your "liquor" component looks like.